# How to optimize a query that uses a dependent subquery

Tags: mysql

I am using this NOT IN query to return inactive users from a single table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT name
                  FROM userlog 
                 WHERE created >= '2019-07-07 00:00:00' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                   AND created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                   AND isSample = 0
     ) inactive 
 WHERE inactive.name NOT IN 
        ( 
     SELECT name AS name 
       FROM userlog 
      WHERE created >= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
        AND created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' AND isSample = 0
        )
```

The describe for this query:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | select_type |   table   | partitions | type |   possiblekeys   |     Keys     | key_len | ref |  rows  | filtered | extra                                  | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |   primary   | <derived2>|  (null)OK  |  ALL |       NULL       |      null    |   NULL  | NULL| 50000  |  100.00  | using where                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 |   subquery  |  userlog  |  (null)OK  | range| *list of indexes |   nameindex  |   774   | NULL| 1000000|  10.00   | using index condition                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 |   derived   |  userlog  |  (null)OK  | range| *list of indexes |   nameindex  |   774   | NULL| 500000 |  10.00   | using index condition; using temporary |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I did not want to query based on name because the name could possibly change, but their ID will never change, so I query using the ID instead. I use the same query, I just change the fields

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT(id) AS id
                 FROM userlog 
                 WHERE created >= '2019-07-07 00:00:00' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                 AND created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                 AND isSample = '0'
     ) inactive 
  WHERE inactive.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id AS id
       FROM userlog 
       WHERE created >= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
       AND created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' 
       AND isSample = '0')
```

Now the describe for this query is not the same as above:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |   select_type    |   table   | partitions |     type     |   possiblekeys   |     Keys     | key_len | ref |  rows  | filtered | extra                                  | 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |     primary      | <derived2>|  (null)OK  |      ALL     |       NULL       |      null    |   NULL  | NULL| 50000  |  100.00  | using where                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 |dependent subquery|  userlog  |  (null)OK  |index_subquery| *list of indexes |   countindex |   768   | func|   892  |   0.61   | using where; full scan on null key     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 |     derived      |  userlog  |  (null)OK  |     range    | *list of indexes |    idindex   |   774   | NULL| 500000 |  10.00   | using index condition; using temporary |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The query now uses a dependent sub-query and it is doing a full table scan, which is insanely slow on my table(20+ million records). I've noticed that the ID query is not using the idindex, but it is using my count index. If I separate each query on it's own, they both use the ID index, but when they are combined for the NOT IN, the count index is used.

Here are my indexes:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  TABLE  | NON_UNIQUE | KEY NAME | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULL | INDEX_TYPE |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     |countindex|       1      |      id     |     A     |    75000    |   255    |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     |countindex|       2      |      pk     |     A     |  11500000   |   null   |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     |nameindex |       1      |   created   |     A     |   6800000   |   null   |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     |nameindex |       2      |    sample   |     A     |  13500000   |   null   |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     |nameindex |       3      |    name     |     A     |   24000000  |   null   |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     | idindex  |       1      |      id     |     A     |    75000    |    512   |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     | idindex  |       2      |   created   |     A     |   22000000  |   null   |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userlog |      1     | idindex  |       3      |   sample    |     A     |   20500000  |   null   |  NULL  |  YES |   BTREE    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Does anyone have an idea why it is using that other index?

Additionally, is there a way that I could optimize the ID query so that this isn't an issue?

If I am missing any information, I can update the question.

**EDITS:**

Here is the update explain for the answer below:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |   select_type    |   table   | partitions |     type     |   possiblekeys   |     Keys     | key_len |   ref   |  rows  | filtered | extra                                              | 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |     primary      |     t1    |  (null)OK  |     range    | *list of indexes |  nameindex   |   774   |   NULL  | 500000 |   10.00  | using index condition; using where; using temporary|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 |dependent subquery|     t2    |  (null)OK  |     ref      | *list of indexes |  idonlyindex |   768   | db.t1.id|   892  |   0.61   | using where;                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

NOTE: idonlyindex is an index only on the id field

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: Can you explain the business logic that you are trying to implement here ? I feel you are unnecessarily using subqueries here and can be solved with combinations of logical operator in your `Where` clause instead.

Comment: Sure, I am tracking a users activity on a weekly basis, but they become inactive after 30 days of no use. So the general concept for the query is if they are inactive for the last 30 days, but they were active in the 7 days prior to the 30 days then they are considered inactive.

Comment: In your second query you are checking `inactive.name` against a log ID, that won't work. That query should be invalid, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am not sure what to tell you, all the queries work on their own or together, just the second query above takes literally hours to run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Subqueries, you can approach this problem using `GROUP BY` with conditional `HAVING` clause based filtering:

```
SELECT id 
FROM userlog 
WHERE isSample = '0' 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING 
  /* No activity in last 30 days */
  NOT SUM(created >= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
          AND created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59') 
  AND 
  /* Activity in 7 days prior to last 30 days */
  SUM(created >= '2019-07-07 00:00:00' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
      AND created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

---

Another approach can be utilizing [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT t1.id
FROM userlog AS t1
WHERE t1.isSample = '0' 
  AND t1.created >= '2019-07-07 00:00:00' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  AND t1.created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM userlog AS t2 
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id 
                    AND t2.isSample = '0' 
                    AND t2.created >= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                    AND t2.created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59')
```

---

Try both the queries and check which one is more *performant*. You *may* also need to define a Composite Index on `(isSample, id, created)`

Comment: I would delete the first query, if I were you. Summing booleans is probably not productive.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I feel that MySQL optimization *may* kick in, and will *short-circuit* the summation as soon as the first row is found. The reason I have two queries, is I want OP to compare their performance, for my understanding also :-)

Comment: Well, let's see what happens when R Wri runs these queries.

Comment: First query does not use indexes so it will be much too slow. 

I am testing the second query now and will see how long it takes and report back

Comment: @RWri It will use the index, if suitable indexes are defined. Check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thank you for that. I'll add the appropriate index and see what happens.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya First query I could not get to utilize an index at all. Second query is still way too slow(Still currently running 1.5 hours). For reference using my above query using name instead of id the query is 6 minutes.

Comment: @RWri yeah first query cannot use Index, due to `SUM()` as pointed out by @KIKOSoftware as well. Did you define the composite index `(id, isSample, created)`

Comment: @RWri can you please update me with the `EXPLAIN .. ` result of the second query

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I've updated in the edit section of the main post. Interestingly enough it is using my nameindex and not my idindex now

Comment: @RWri I think without looking at real data, it is difficult.. try to setup a SQL fiddle with atleast 500 random sample data rows..

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I understand. I've quickly set up http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4460b9/2 500 rows was too much for their 8000 character limit, but I got 100

Comment: @RWri why do you have `userId` defined as mediumtext in the fiddle ? If it is really `mediumtext`, then this is a bigger area of concern. Ideally it should have been an `int` field.

Comment: @RWri check this fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61zvwHajub1ueZUY2JSCmb/0 

I have added an index; and both the queries are able to utilize the index.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya userId should actually be a long, I must not have paid attention to what it was in the fiddle. I will check out your fiddle now and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196574/discussion-between-r-wri-and-madhur-bhaiya).

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  id
 FROM userlog 
    WHERE 
        (  created >= '2019-07-07 00:00:00' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                 AND created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                 AND isSample = 0
         )

    AND    name NOT IN 
         ( 
             SELECT u1.name  
              FROM userlog as u1
             WHERE u1created >= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
                AND u1created <= '2019-07-13 23:59:59' AND u1.isSample = 0
         )
```

If you are using `name` column to to filter, adding index would be nice.
Adding parenthesis is to override the logic to process that independently from the 2nd logic.

Comment: I am trying to avoid filtering by name since it is subject to change whereas id will never change